# Scrolling through page Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

[image: 9 buttons]
i want to make my page scrollable.
as you can see in image that, there are 9 buttons and no room for adding more buttons
so, how can i add more buttons and make page scrollable so that any button can be selected?
i already tried to enclose all these button in scroll viewer but it didn't worked, it scrolls but when i release my finger from screen it quickly goes back i.e. i can see buttons which are at bottom but can't select those.

Comment: well, it indeed worked like charm !! 
thanks a ton !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give a particular height to your scrollviewer because by default s always get to set to the height of the contents in it so no scrolling :).
Just Set the Height Property of your Scrollviewer to some value. Like:-

```
<ScrollViewer Height="700">
  Content..
</ScrollViewer>
```

cheers :)